# How are static keys loaded onto the card in globalplatfrom achitecture?

Tags: java, smartcard, javacard, globalplatform

Having a quite newbie problem. But this question lingered for a very long time: We all know session keys used in SCP01/02/03 are derived from static keying materials. But I cannot figure out how those static keys are loaded on card! Maybe I read the spec too carelessly, yet I had searched the whole paper relating to those words of interest and I found nothing. Any boss could enlighten me? And could you by the way tell me something about the personalization process on its purpose? Please.

---

For those of you who might not have known the usage of the data "diversification data" just like me here I quote a paragraph from "GlobalPlatform Card Specifications 2.1.1 & 2.1 17 FAQ":

### Typically, smart card schemes diversify the static keys (e.g. the Secure Channel Keys listed in Appendix D.2 – Cryptographic Keys) that are loaded on any smart card, so that a security breach in one card does not compromise the entire card base. Hence, the presence of ‘key diversification data’ in the INITIALIZE UPDATE response described in appendices D.4.1.6 and E.5.1.6 – INITIALIZE UPDATE Response message. Such information is specific to key management and card management schemes: for example, it may be a unique card identifier allowing the off-card system to identify and/or compute which static keys a particular card carries. In summary, it is an operational technique to avoid storing in an off-card database as many sets of keys as cards are issued, which may potentially be millions.

Comment: Have a look at PUT KEY command...

Answer (score 2):

Your smartcard usually ships with default keys installed on the card. For most cards this is 404142..4F for all 3 DES keys in SCP02. So you might try the default key, otherwise ask your vendor/supplier/chip manufacturer for the keys. Beware that the chip locks itself after certain amount of unsuccessful tries..

To change the keys for operational lifecycle, Global Platform offers the `PUTKEY` command, often also other proprietary chip-specific methods (e.g. `STORE DATA` or completely proprietary) may exist. If `PUTKEY` does not work, contact your vendor/supplier/chip manufacturer.

Comment: Many thanks! I got your point for the most part, but if that's the case, there is also a data column returned from the card response in INITIALIZE UPDATE called 'Key diversification data', in the spec it serves as "The key diversification data is data typically used by a backend system to derive the card static keys." Can u explain on that? Many thanks again.

Comment: Or is that just an ID of the card manufacture to look up its static key?

Comment: Strange, the diversification data serves to derive the *session keys*, not any static keys as far as I know. Can you point out the relevant part of the standard?

Comment: Most cards will probably have a very specific key set, but not the ones you get with a development package or very low amount order, e.g. < 100 K chips :)

Comment: @MaartenBodewes My 'quoted' reference from above comment was copied from a  specific description of that data section 7.1.1.1 GPC_2.2_D_SCP03_v1.1.1, too bad I cannot figure how to load pictures in comment. :) Maybe there is some typo in the spec?

Comment: @MaartenBodewes AFAIK the 'Key diversification data' returned in `INITIALIZE UPDATE` is constant for given card and is used for deriving its unique card keys (via EMV CPS or VISA2 key derivation function). These unique card keys are stored inside the card (via `PUT KEY` or any other proprietary method). During each SCP session a new session keys are derived from those card keys and protocol nonces. In case there is no EMV/VISA diversification some other static keys (e.g. well known 4041..4F keys) are stored as card keys and used to derive the session keys during the mutual authentication.

Answer (score 0):

With a brandnew NXP JavaCard and `jcshell` terminal. To change a static first key of value `1D9A55C27970FACEBABEDEC0DE4CCE55`:

```
/terminal
/atr
/card
init-update
ext-auth enc
/set-var k 1D9A55C27970FACEBABEDEC0DE4CCE55
set-key 1/1/DES-ECB/${k} 1/2/DES-ECB/${k} 1/3/DES-ECB/${k}
put-keyset -m add -r 1 1
```

Remove the card and put back the card and then authenticate using new static key:

```
/card
/set-var k 1D9A55C27970FACEBABEDEC0DE4CCE55
set-key 1/1/DES-ECB/${k} 1/2/DES-ECB/${k} 1/3/DES-ECB/${k}
init-update 1
```

Here are some things that I observed. A brandnew card default key index is `FF` which means the static key is from manufacturing default. Once a new key is introduced, the default static keys is forever lost and the key index shall no longer be `FF`. Since we set the static key index to `1`, then `init-update` must supply this index number. Otherwise, the card will chose this index number.

I can continue adding more static keys, but not delete. Static keys can only be changed in value or reposition in index. I'm not messing with the 10 bytes diversification data yet, but I see them to be fixed for each card.